# Bluetooth sbc parameters

Tags: bluetooth-audio, a2dp

From http://soundexpert.org/news/-/blogs/bluetooth-audio-quality-a2dp, and [How do I determine which A2DP codecs my phone supports/is currently using?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26410/how-do-i-determine-which-a2dp-codecs-my-phone-supports-is-currently-using), I can see that when I listen to bluetooth audio from my phone to my car, I am getting sbc with these parameters:

Middle Quality Joint Stereo
Samp Freq 44.1 kHz
Bitpool value 35
Resulting Frame length 83 bytes
Resulting bit rate 229 kb/s
Block length 16
Allocation method = Loudness
Subbands 8

Can someone share an equation of how these parameters relate to each other?  Does any sbc at 44.1 KHz and bitrate 229 kb/s have to have bitpool = 35 and frame length 83 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found my answer:

Direct link: https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=303201

Alternative: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications and search for a2dp

The equations are in section 12.9.